# A question about Folland's definition of parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Here is Folland's definition of parametrization in his book *Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications* Chapter 11.2 Hausdorff measure.

> We now consider lower-dimensional sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $1 \le k \le n$, a **k-dimensional $C^1$ submanifold** of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with the following property:
>
> For each $x \in M$ there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, an open set $V\subset\mathbb{R}^k$, and an injective map $f:V\to U$ of class $C^1$ such that $f(V) = M\cap U$ and the differential $D_xf$ - i.e., the linear map from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose matrix is $\left[\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right)(x)\right]$ - is
> injective for each $x\in V$. Such an $f$ is called a parametrization of $M \cap U$.

Compare this definition with the definition of smooth manifold, which requires the coordinate map is a local homeomorphism.

I want to show in Folland's definition, the local inverse $f^{-1}:M\cap U\to V$ is continuous with respect to the subspace topology of $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

But in Do Carmo's book *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces*, in the definition of regular surface, local homeomorphism is required.

Thanks in advance if you can give me any hint (or counterexample)!

Thanks to @Kenny Wong's answer (figure 8 space) below. We can conclude that, "figure 8 space" is a *$1$-dimensional $C^1$ manifold* in Folland's definition, but in the mean time, it is not a topological manifold if it is equipped with subspace topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $p \in V$, and pick an open ball $B(p, \delta)$ such that its closure $\overline{B(p, \delta)}$ lies inside $V$.

Consider the restriction of $f$ to the closed ball $\overline{B(p, \delta)}$. This is a continuous injective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space. Therefore, this map is a homeomorphism onto its image.

The restriction of this map to the open ball $B(p, \delta)$ is then also a homeomorphism onto its image.

So at the very least, the following statement is true:

> For every $p \in V$, there exists an open neighbourhood $V'$ of $p$ with $V' \subset V$ such that $f|_{V'} : V' \to f(V')$ is a homeomorphism.

---

However, taking your definition as written, it is **not** necessarily true that $f: V \to f(V)$ is itself a homeomorphism.

For example, suppose that $V = (-\pi, \pi)$ and suppose that $U = \mathbb R^2$. Let $f : V \to U$ be the "figure-of-eight" map,
$$ f(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t).$$
Take $M$ to be its image, $f(V)$. By your definition, $M$ is a $1$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

Please sketch this to get a feel for what this looks like, and observe that $f$ is *not* a homeomorphism onto its image, since the inverse $f^{-1}|_{f(V)}$ is discontinuous at $(0, 0)$.

[That said, the restrictions $f|_{(-\delta, \delta)}$, $f|_{(\pi - \delta, \pi)}$ and $f|_{(-\pi, -\pi + \delta)}$ are all homeomorphisms onto their respective images, so there is no contradiction with what we said earlier.]